# Custom validation of CKEditor (RTE) in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, ckeditor, rich-text-editor

I'm using ASP.NET MVC & CKEditor (Basic) to get input (almost exactly like this stack overflow RTE.) User's are limited to bold,italic,links.

I'm assuming I need to validate this server-side, incase someone issues CURL requests to my controller with any desired HTML in it. (I.E so they weren't limited by client-side validation).

So I need to allow, bold, italic, link tags, lists, but absolutely nothing else, how can this be achieved? I'll have a custom validator on my view model, but what is the best way to structure this custom validator? What to look for etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be achieved through regex and negative lookahead.

Something like that `<(?!br/|br /|a|/a|strong|/strong|b|/b|i|/i|ul|/ul|li|/li>).+?>` would match all tags except `<br />`, `<a></a>`, `<strong></strong>`, `<b></b>`, `<i></i>`, `<ul></ul>`, and `<li></li>`.

Then you could replace the matched occurences with an empty string.

For example this input (tested on regextester.com) :

```
test <a href="http://www.test.com">test link</a>
Some <strong>text in bold</strong> and <b>another one</b> but also something
in <i>italic</i>
<ul>
    <li>Now</li>
    <li>a list</li>
</ul>
<table>
    <tr>
         <td>And a table</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br />
<hr />
```

Would become :

```
test <a href="http://www.test.com">test link</a>
Some <strong>text in bold</strong> and <b>another one</b> but also something 
in <i>italic</i>
<ul>
    <li>Now</li>
    <li>a list</li>
</ul>

And a table

<br />
```